# Can't find maximum of a function on a region

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

for `h=0.2`

I'm trying to find the maximum value of

```
(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2)
```

subject to

```
8.1 < x < 8.5
```

I've tried pretty much every combination of:

**Functions:**

`FindMaximum[]`, `MaxValue[]`

**Region (reg):**

```
x \ [Element] Interval[{8.1,8.5}]
x \ [Element] Interval[8.1,8.5]
{x,8.1,8.5}
x, Interval[{8.1,8.5}]
x, Interval[8.1,8.5]
x \ [Element] Interval[{8.1,8.5}], x
x \ [Element] Interval[8.1,8.5], x
```

*I even tried using 81/10 and 85/10 but that didn't work either..*

**Expression:**

```
(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2)
{(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2) , reg}
Assuming[reg , -h^2/(3*x^2)
```

---

I'm getting errors like:

> The variable `x\[Element]Interval[{81/10,17/2}]` cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.
>
> The variable `x\[Element]Interval[{8.099999999,8.500000001}]` cannot  be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.
>
> Constraints in `{x\[Element]Interval[{8.099999999,8.500000001}]}` are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with `Unequal` (`!=`) are not supported.

One time it told me the max value of this function was `-7.34642395*10^-35`.

Honestly I know I'm doing something really stupid but I can't figure out what.

Comment: `With[{h = 0.2}, FindMaximum[{(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), 8.1 <= x <= 8.5}, {x, 8.3}]]`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I had to tweek it a bit for what I was using it for after I posted the question. It works better than what I have but I have:...............

`With[{h = 0.2}, 
 FindMaximum[{Abs[(h^2/3)*(-1/x^2)], 8.3 <= x <= 8.7}, x]]` = `{0.000193497, {x -> 8.30103}}`

...............But............... 

`Abs[(-0.2^2/(3*8.3^2))]` = `0.0001935452654`

Answer (score 8):

You should be aware of the fact that your problem may be somewhat ill-posed. Your function simplifies to the following expression:

```
Simplify[(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2)]

(* Out: h^2/(3 x^2) *)
```

The difference of the function's values at the two extrema of your interval is ca. $0.0005\ h^2$. Since $h^2$ is a positive quantity (for $h\ne0$) and the function is monotonically decreasing (plot it), its maximum is attained at $x=8.1$, i.e. infinitesimally outside the region defined by your constraints; in that case `Maximize` & co. will return the supremum and the closest specifiable point (from [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)).

---

Many approaches seem to produce a result when correct syntax is used:

```
FindMaximum[{(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), 8.1 < x < 8.5}, x]
Maximize[{(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), 8.1 < x < 8.5}, x]
```

However, I was intrigued by the idea of using an `Interval` as a region specification, although technically it is *NOT* equivalent to your desired constraints, because `Interval[{8.1, 8.5}]` represents the *closed* interval that includes both end points (i.e. $8.1\le x\le8.5$, whereas you want them excluded.

My first attempt had me scratching my head though:

```
Maximize[(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), x ∈ Interval[{8.1, 8.5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It turns out that the accepted syntax for specifying that $x$ belongs to that interval is `{x} ∈ Interval[{8.1, 8.5}]`. Using that form, the optimization works fine:

```
Maximize[(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), {x} ∈ Interval[{8.1, 8.5}]]
(* Out: {0.000203221, {x -> 8.1}} *)
```

This did not strike me as immediately obvious, nor did I find it referenced in the documentation for `Interval` or other optimizers that accept geometric regions. I am still wondering whether I am missing something and I *should* have expected that. Hopefully I'll update if I find out more.

Comment: the requirement for the `{ }` is inconsistent with the docs for `Element`. Possibly should be labeled as a bug?

Comment: @george2079 Use of vectors (`{` `}`) is consistent when you consider `Interval` to be a geometric region when `Element` is used with it. Points in geometric regions are always coordinates that are described by vectors, even when those vectors are of only one dimension. Plain `x` is also valid, but at that case it's considered to be a symbolic vector, which needs to be handled accordingly (for instance, with `Indexed[x, 1]` in equations, instead of being treated as a number.

Comment: For symbolic vector case, consider `Maximize[(-h^2/3)*(-1/Indexed[x, 1]^2), x \[Element] Interval[{8.1, 8.5}]] (* {0.000203221, {x -> {8.1}}} *)`

Comment: Makes sense, but I still find the docs lacking.

Answer (score 8):

This is really an extended comment about region-based constrained variables.

When you see `Element` in the variable section of a function such as `Maximize`, it always means you are dealing with *geometric* regions, although it is not necessarily immediately obvious. Values in geometric regions are always vectors, even when that vector has a length of one. So it happens to be in the case of `Interval`, when it is interpreted to be a region. Like some graphics primitives, `Interval` has second meaning in this context. This kind of constrained variable is declared in a form like `Element[{x}, Interval[{0, 1}]]`. Compare this with `Element[{x, y}, Disk[]]`.

So, such declarations should have curly braces, right? Not quite. There are also symbolic vectors which are a feature that isn't documented very well. They don't have curly braces, even if they involve both `Element` and a geometric region. These are such as `Element[v, Interval[{0, 1}]]` or `Element[v, Disk[]]`. Sometimes these symbolic vectors can be used directly also on the equation side; consider `Maximize[Norm[v], Element[v, Disk[]]]`, for instance. (Sadly mixing normal and symbolic vectors doesn't work as nicely as one might hope.)

This form allows for accessing individual components of symbolic vectors using `Indexed`, which is used like this: `Maximize[Indexed[x, 1] - Indexed[x, 1]^2, Element[x, Interval[{0, 1}]]]`.

Note that in case of list-based coordinates, results list those variables as individual scalars:

```
Maximize[y + x^2, Element[{x, y}, Disk[]]]

(* {5/4, {x -> -(Sqrt[3]/2), y -> 1/2}} *)
```

... but in the case of symbolic vectors, as vector values:

```
Maximize[Indexed[v, 2] + Indexed[v, 1]^2, Element[v, Disk[]]]

(* {5/4, {v -> {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2}}} *)
```

`Interval` is just one of these regions that can be used, and its elements are also vectors.

**EDIT**: A side note: `FindMaximum` doesn't understand region constraints in the variable declaration part. This is understandable, but unfortunately it doesn't understand that in its constraints either, which saddens me. This does work, though (as it expands to normal inequalities):

```
With[{h = 0.2}, 
 FindMaximum[{(-h^2/3)*(-1/x^2), 
   RegionMember[Interval[{8.1, 8.5}], {x}]}, x]]
```