# How to plot a given function over its domain

Tags: plotting

How can I plot

```
Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)
```

in all its domain?

```
Domain = FunctionDomain[{ Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, x]
```

Domain is :  `x <= -1 || 0 <= x <= 1`

I tried

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, {x, -100, -1}]
```

but I really dont know how!

Comment: What are you asking?...

Comment: I want to plot the function Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1) and I cant

Comment: `Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, {x, -10, 1}]`?

Comment: The curly braces are not necessary here.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one approach:

```
Plot[Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1), 
    Element[x, ImplicitRegion[FunctionDomain[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, x], x]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I wasn't aware you can use region specification directly on `Plot` like that.

Comment: BTW, I believe the pedantically correct way would be to write `Element[{x}, ...]`. Otherwise `x` is actually treated as an one-dimensional vector, and it might not always work as it should as a scalar.

Comment: There's probably some difference between `x` and `{x}` in `Plot`, but I don't know of any off the top of my head. If you find any, let me know.

Comment: I suspect `Plot` does some magic with its argument, since it knows that it cannot be multidimensional vector, anyway. Normally there's a difference between `x` and `{x}` in these cases (and documentation indicates that `{x}` should be used), but now it seems impossible to spot from insides of `Plot`.

Comment: I know `Plot` does some magic with its argument. :-)

Comment: For a comment on why I think these variations should differ, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108678/3056 .

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you are looking for something like the following.  It uses the `Show` function to combine the two plots.

```
Show[Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, {x, -10, -1}], 
 Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, {x, 0, 1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: @JMM, `Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^3]/(x^2 + 1)}, {x, -10, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {-10, 0}]` is enough

Comment: @SofiaPazJimenezCastillo Don't forget to accept one of the answers by clicking the check mark.