# Simplify behavior: assumption as Interval versus assumption as bounds

Tags: simplifying-expressions, regions, computational-geometry

I am using MMA V11.2 under Linux

I am surprised by this:

```
In: Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]],{x>0,x<Pi}]
Out: Sin[x]        <-- ok

In: Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]],Element[x,Interval[{0,Pi}]]]
Out: Abs[Sin[x]]   <-- not ok
```

**Questions:**

1. is it the same for more recent versions of MMA?
2. is it possible to get the right simplification using   `Element[x,Interval[{0,Pi}]]]` 
   (which has the advantage of using `Region` which is a more conceptual approach)?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain why the latter one does what it does, but `Element` treats `Interval`s as geometric regions, and members of those geometric regions are vectors, even when they are of single dimension. (I don't think this is really properly documented anywhere.) Changing the code to `Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]], Element[{x}, Interval[{0, Pi}]]]` gives the expected result.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I have not thought about that. Maybe you can cut/copy this to an answer I will upvote :)

Comment: Related earlier comment by me: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108678/3056

Comment: Wrote a bit more about it now that I remembered extra details.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Element` treats `Interval`s as geometric regions, and members of those geometric regions are vectors, even when they are of single dimension. (I don't think this is really properly documented anywhere - I tried to look at documentation of both.)

The fact that there are two different interpretations of an `Interval` - the old, and the new bought by geometric regions functionality - and the fact they're inherently single-dimensional objects causes repeated confusion on this specific manner.

Changing the code to

```
Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]], Element[{x}, Interval[{0, Pi}]]]
```

gives the expected result:

> Sin[x]

If you don't "list" `x`, it's actually interpreted as a symbolic vector, whose components you can refer with `Indexed` (and without which the symbolic vector probably doesn't make alone sense for `Simplify` as an argument to `Sin`) and the simplification works:

```
Simplify[Abs[Sin[Indexed[x, 1]]], Element[x, Interval[{0, Pi}]]]
```

> Sin[Indexed[x, {1}]]

Sometimes symbolic vectors work even as arguments to functions (on a place of an explicit one), but I have never gotten a grasp when it is supposed to work, and when not. This seems very fragile, or awfully documented at least.