# Simplify with Semi-Infinite Interval

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'd like to `Simplify` an expression using an `Interval` constraint.  [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182097/simplify-behavior-assumption-as-interval-versus-assumption-as-bounds) shows that you need to put the variable in a `{}`, but this still doesn't work:

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], Element[{x}, Interval[{0, Infinity}]]]
(* Re[Sqrt[x]] *)
```

while the seemingly equivalent

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], 0 <= x <= Infinity]
(* Sqrt[x] *)
```

does.  It seems that the `Infinity` is to blame, because

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], Element[{x}, Interval[{0, 10^10}]]]
(* Sqrt[x] *)
```

also works.

Can someone explain the discrepancy?  Should I just use

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], 
  Min[Interval[{0, Infinity}]] <= x <= Max[Interval[{0, Infinity}]]]
(* Sqrt[x] *)
```

?

**Version:**

```
$Version
(* 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018) *)
```

Comment: I don't reproduce your problem: https://imgur.com/a/YkuRAHU

Comment: @corey979 I added my version info to the question.  What's yours?

Comment: `"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"`. Indeed doesn't work in 11.3.

Comment: A quote from ?Interval: "Interval[{min,max}] represents the closed interval that includes both end points", but Sqrt [ \ [Infinity] ] performs DirectedInfinity[1].

Comment: `RegionMember[Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}], {x}]` gives an error suggesting the region is not correctly specified, but `Region`SpecialRegionProperty[Interval[{0, Infinity}], {x}, "ImplicitDescription"]` works fine.  I guess that infinite intervals are not fully incorporated, which should be reported. Whether or not it's a bug, I'd say as a user, I would rather they were fully implemented.  You can use `SpecialRegionProperty` to convert the interval to an inequality for `Simplify`.  (V11.3.0, Jan 2018 Macos).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, that's a more elegant workaround. If you'd add it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that infinite intervals are not fully incorporated, which should be reported to WRI. Whether or not it's a bug, I'd say as a user, I would rather they were fully implemented.

`RegionMember[Interval[{0, Infinity}], {x}]` gives an error `RegionMember::regp` suggesting the region is not correctly specified, but `` Region`SpecialRegionProperty[Interval[{0, Infinity}], {x}, "ImplicitDescription"] `` works fine.  You can use `SpecialRegionProperty` to convert the interval to an inequality for `Simplify`.

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], 
 Region`SpecialRegionProperty[Interval[{0, Infinity}], {x}, 
  "ImplicitDescription"]]
(*  Sqrt[x]  *)
```

The result can also be accomplished with `HalfLine[]`.  Since `Interval[]` is both produced and accepted as input by *Mathematica* functions, I repeat it would be better if intervals were handled more completely.

```
Simplify[Re[Sqrt[x]], Element[{x}, HalfLine[{0}, {1}]]]
(*  Sqrt[x]  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I sent this to WRI support.